# Seperate combination of lists not working

Tags: excel, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

i am trying to generate a combination from two lists A and B.

A(1,2,3,4), B(5,6,7,8)

using this formula `=IF(ROW()-ROW($C$1)+1>COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B),"-",INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW()-ROW($C$1))/COUNTA(B:B)+1))&INDEX(B:B,MOD(ROW()-ROW($C$1),COUNTA(B:B))+1))`
and its working.However,the combinations generated doesn't seem to be seperated by the hyphen `,"-",` in the formula. So they end up like C(15,16,17,18) which should be C(1-5,1-6,1-7,1-8). What's wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

the `,"-",` is not the delimiter but the true condition of `ROW()-ROW($C$1)+1>COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B)`  If you drag the formula past four rows you would get `-` in the cells alone.

You want:

```
=IF(ROW()-ROW($C$1)+1>COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B),"",INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW()-ROW($C$1))/COUNTA(B:B)+1))&"-"&INDEX(B:B,MOD(ROW()-ROW($C$1),COUNTA(B:B))+1))
```